# Scripting Local Policy Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks

Tags: sql-server, installation, scripting

I am working on an automated SQL 2012 install process on Windows 2012 R2 and have everything complete except for one task.  My process launches secpol.msc but I am still required to drill in and manually assign access to Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks to the SQL service account.  Once I close the window the process takes over and installs and configures everything else without user intervention.

I have done extensive internet searching and the closest I have found is this article from 5 years ago by Kendra Little: http://www.littlekendra.com/2009/11/12/automating-sql-local-security-policy-rights-posh-and-ntrights/.

Is there a means via scripting to set Local Security Policies?

Thank You,
Scott

Comment: So I'm not sure I understand the problem. Does Kendra's script not work?

Comment: @AaronBertrand.  I corrected a typo and was able to get it to execute.  Thank You